# Revert "handles improvement request" but keep the rest?

Tags: support, documentation

The following change:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/139205?filter-tags=c%2b%2b

is a good change in itself, but it does not handle the improvement request that it claims to handle.

How can I partially rollback the change such that:

- the actual changes to the document remain intact
- the "handles improvement request" is removed, i.e. the improvement request remains open

---

To clarify the above example: I am asking for an improvement/example that uses a lambda function as a comparator. But apparently the person who made the change saw the keyword "C++11" and thought that shortening the example by using some C++11 features is what the request is about - they didn't include the comparator as requested.

Comment: i would just create a new improvement request.